# Refrence for this sentence in vedas

Tags: vedas, rig-veda

In class 6 history books, this line is quoted frm rigveda to prove that Varna migration was easy in early Vedic period.

> 'l am a singer; my father is a physician, my mother is a grinder of corn . ' writes a person in a hymn.

Is this line really present in rigveda or any other Veda??? Pls cite refrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the referenced verse found in Rigveda 9 Mandala's 112th Suktam's, 3rd Verse = 9.112.3

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc838489.html

> Sanskrit text [Accents, Plain, Transliterated]:
>
> का॒रुर॒हं त॒तो भि॒षगु॑पलप्र॒क्षिणी॑ न॒ना । नाना॑धियो वसू॒यवोऽनु॒ गा
> इ॑व तस्थि॒मेन्द्रा॑येन्दो॒ परि॑ स्रव ॥ कारुरहं ततो भिषगुपलप्रक्षिणी
> नना । नानाधियो वसूयवोऽनु गा इव तस्थिमेन्द्रायेन्दो परि स्रव ॥
>
> kārur ahaṃ tato bhiṣag upalaprakṣiṇī nanā | nānādhiyo vasūyavo 'nu gā
> iva tasthimendrāyendo pari srava ||
>
> English translation:
>
> “I am the singer; papa is the physician, mamma throws the corn upon
> the grinding stones; having various occupations, desiring riches we
> remain (in the world) like cattle (in the stall); flow, Indu, for
> Indra.”
>
> Commentary by Sāyaṇa: Ṛgveda-bhāṣya
>
> The singeṛ..papa...mamma: kāruḥ = maker of praises; 'maker', 'poet';
> tataḥ and nānā mean father (dada) and mother; or son and daughter
> respectively

...also...

This is the *Jamison and Brereton* translation for it

> 3. 
>
> I am a bard, Papa a healer, and Mama is pushing a pestle.
>
> Having varying thoughts but (all) seeking goods, we follow (goods)
>
> like cows.
>
> - O drop, flow around for Indra

Personally I don't see how this can imply easier or random varna transmigration in the same birth. To say this verse imply choosing varna as per one's own whims and work seems like too much stretching. Maybe a traditional Acharya can only comment, which I think will be what I have already written.

Comment: I don't see any controversy or solving any controversy in this verse, it's just a kid I presume singing about his life.